# Add extra field in story content type using hook without CCK

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I want to add extra field in story content type using hook, I don't want to use CCK, because am trying something different.

Please tell some suggestion with hook method.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not use CCK, you will have to create your database table and code to add the form field, validate the form field, capture the data and save it in your field. I know cck can be a monster, but it does all this for you.  I'd be happy to give you more info on all of this, but it is quite lengthy

Comment: Seriously, CCK was moved to core in D7 for a very good reason.

Comment: There are a number of reasons why many CCK-like features were moved into Drupal 7, but there are just as many reasons why you may not want to use the Fields API and prefer custom code/schema for many use cases.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of reasons that you may want to do this without CCK or Fields, and the best example is found at the node_example module in the [examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) project which can be found at: http://drupalcode.org/project/examples.git/tree/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/node_example. You can also view the documentation on [api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/node_example%21node_example.module/6).

The short version is that you're going to have to define your own node type using hook_node_info() and then define all the hooks for _load(), _insert(), _update(), _delete(), _access(), _validate(), and _view() in addition to defining your schema in your hook_schema and managing your tables on your own.

Sadly there is no good example for Drupal 7 as the node_example module for 7 was converted to use fields instead of the hooks listed above, which are still fully documented on api.drupal.org (they do now typically act on an array of nodes instead of a single node, but are otherwise identical).